# Get Variable name of the table

Tags: matlab

For Example we have such a table as input

```
>> TmpCell{1}

ans = 

    starttime      endtime  
    __________    __________

    7.3609e+05    7.3609e+05
    7.3609e+05    7.3609e+05
    7.3609e+05    7.3609e+05
     7.361e+05     7.361e+05
     7.361e+05     7.361e+05
     7.361e+05     7.361e+05
     7.361e+05     7.361e+05
     7.361e+05     7.361e+05
     7.361e+05     7.361e+05
     7.361e+05     7.361e+05
```

If I want to extract data from the table its simple that I use `table2array()` but I have this problem that I also have to read the table varible name as a string which is 'starttime' and 'endtime' assuming the variablenames of table I take as an input are not the same for all the tables I have to read , how can I extract that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access this via the [`Properties.VariableNames`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tableproperties.html#property_variablenames) property of the `table` object which will return a cell array of strings representing the variable names.

```
t = table(rand(4,1), rand(4,1), rand4, 1), 'VariableNames', {'a', 'b', 'c'});

       a          b          c
    _______    _______    _______

    0.17587    0.34112    0.24285
    0.72176    0.60739    0.91742
    0.47349    0.19175    0.26906
    0.15272    0.73843     0.7655   


t.Properties.VariableNames
%   'a'     'b'     'c'
```